# ConEmu only attach if it is running

Tags: windows, conemu

I have some batches that start applications in the windows startup folder. If ConEmu is registered as the default, ConEmu outputs errors such as "cannot attach to process because it does not exist".

I would like for cmd scripts to be attached only if ConEmu already runs. Otherwise use the default cmd.exe.

I have "force ConEmy as default", "Register on startup", "Aggressive Mode" and "Automatic attach" enabled. I tried disabling them one at a time, and even combinations but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable [Force ConEmu as default terminal](http://conemu.github.io/en/SettingsDefTerm.html)
2. Disable "Register ...", "Aggressive ..." and "Leave in TSA".
3. Done. In some cases logoff/logon may be required.
4. Always use latest ConEmu build.